# How to check if connection to server is lost in the android?

Tags: java, android, networking, connection

From my android application, how can detect if connection to the server whose IP for example is 192.168.32.232 is lost? Once connection is lost, I want write a service class which will keep on check for connection to the server in the background. If connection is lost my app should show a dialogue box.

Comment: On a different note: `192.168.32.232` doesn't seem like IP of an server. This resembles to one provided by local network.

Comment: How do you initiate the connection between your app and your server ? TCP protocol ?

Comment: I just have to check for connection with a server, irrespective of the way I initiated it.

Comment: It can't be 'irrespective of the way you initiated it'. You may have a socket, an input stream, an output stream, an `HttpURLConnection`, ... Which it is determines the shape of the answer. Details are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with a BroadcastReceiver (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html#detect-changes) to peridically check your connection with server, by calling the Kristiyan Varbanov function